# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

Running this code.  Works fine on local dev server, but not on live server.

```
try
{
    var qq =
    db.tblConstructReleaseDownloads
    .Where(c => c.UserID.HasValue && c.UserID.Value == userID)
    .OrderBy(c => c.DateStarted)
    .ThenBy(c => c.ReleaseID);

    var query = db.GetCommand(qq).CommandText;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(query + "<br><br>");

    foreach (var d in qq)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ID:" + d.ID + "<br>");
    }
```

This throws the error:

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.
```

The command text it prints out is:

```
SELECT     ID, ReleaseID, IP, DateCompleted, BytesServed, UserID, DateStarted, BytesPerSecond, TrackerVisitID
FROM         tblConstructReleaseDownloads AS t0
WHERE     (UserID IS NOT NULL) AND (UserID = @p0)
ORDER BY DateStarted, ReleaseID
```

I run this query on the live database and it works fine, no errors.

Anyone got any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the columns returned by the query contains a `NULL` value in the database on the live server but not on the dev server.
Because the corresponding property in your domain model is defined as `int` and not `int?` you should mark that column as *not nullable*.

Comment: I'm looking at the results returned by the query, and none of the relevant columns contain null values.  UserID, dateStarted and releaseID all have non null values.

Comment: @TomGullen: There are a lot more columns in that query. Each will get assigned to a property in your domain model and can cause that error. You also need to look at `BytesServed`, `BytesPerSecond` and `TrackerVisitID`. I suspect the last one is the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I changed the query to select only the rows I need.  Will ensure my domain model matches database as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC check your model. I wrestled with this for about 3 hours before I checked the model and changed the int value to Nullable int. Works like a charm now.